# unable to predict the output when a function returning reference is written on LHS

Tags: c++, reference

I know following about reference

eg. `int &ref=x;`
then ref and x are the names of same locations in memory.
Memory is not allocated for reference unlike pointers.

I was writting a simple swap program in C++ using references which I successfully wrote.

Then i decided to try out what happens when a function which returns reference is LHS of an expression and now I am unable to predict the output of the below code.

```
#include<iostream.h>

int &  swap(int &,int &);   //function returns reference
void main()
{
    int x=10,y=20;
    int &ref1=x,&ref2=y;
    swap(ref1,ref2)=x;         //what happens here?
    cout<<x<<y;
}

int & swap(int &ref1,int &ref2)
{
    int temp;         
    temp=ref1;        //swap   
    ref1=ref2;        //code
    ref2=temp;        //here

    return ref2;      //tried out this(has nothing to do with swapping)
}
```

O/P 20 20

Comment: Educate people that write such code not to do it. If they insist on not changing, find a way to stop working with them. If you are one of those people, please change how you write code.

Comment: Memory may be allocated for references.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible outcomes:

1. "2010"
2. "2020"

It depends on whether `x` on the right side is read before or after calling `swap` on the left.

The standard does not proscribe which happens, only that they are not interleaved.

Comment: yes, looks like it. Just keep in mind that it could change without apparent cause.

Comment: I've experimented a bit: `x` always gets evaluated first, however the result depends on the kind of `operator=` is defined.
if `operator=(int&)` is used then the result is "20 20" (i.e. the reference of `x` is used). If `operator=(int)` is used then the value of `x` is copied before swap() and the result is "20 10".